# Reverse engineering a JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Taking a javascript class in which there are a lot of code examples but not a whole lot of explanation of how any of it works. I *thought* I had a solid understanding of the various operators and standard functions, but the `else if` statement below is just mind boggling to me. Can someone please shed a little light, thanks.

```
function validatePassword(password) {
 try {
   if (document.forms[0].password.value != document.forms[0].password_confirm.value)
     throw "You did not enter the same password.";
   else if (!/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,15}$/.test(password))
     throw "You did not enter a valid password.";
 }
```

Specifically this: 
`(!/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,15}$/.test(password))`

Comment: Look at [Regular Expressions MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: `(!/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,15}$/.test(password))` is a regex (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). The password needs to match a series of filters in order to be accepted.

Comment: The various characters are a regex expression, and `test()` is testing if the password matches the regex string.

Comment: The first statement checks that the value of the field with the name `password` matches the value of the field with the name `password_confirm`, the second `else if` checks that the password contains a certain set of characters to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking down

```
!/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,15}$/.test(password)
```

---

`/.../.test(password)` is checking whether the string value of `password` matches the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to the left.

`.{6,15}` requires `password` to be between 6 and 15 UTF-16 code-units in length and contain only non-newline characters.

`(?=.*\d)` is a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that only matches when there is a digit in the string.  The `.*\d` means 0 or more (`*`) of any line-character (`.`) followed by a digit `\d`.

`(?=.*[a-z])` and `(?=.*[A-Z])` similarly require at least one lower-case ASCII letter, and one upper-case one.

Answer (score 2):

It's a regular expression (regex). Character by character:

- `(` Open paren, nothing tricky here.
- `!` "Not" operator, negating what comes next.
- `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,15}$/` Big nasty regex. Breaking this part even further (ignoring the slashes as they're just delimiters):

  > - `^` Must match start of given string.
  > - `(?=.*\d)` lookahead; checks for zero or more characters and then a digit. Basically, makes sure the password has at least one digit.
  > - `(?=.*[a-z])` another lookahead; checks for zero or more characters and then a lowercase letter, ensuring the password contains at least one lowercase letter.
  > - `(?=.*[A-Z])` a third lookahead; this one makes sure the password contains at least one uppercase letter.
  > - `.{6,15}$` matches any character between 6 and 15 times, then matches end of string. Since all we've done since the start anchor (`^`) is lookaheads, no characters have actually been consumed yet. If we didn't need to confirm upper/lower/digit, we could have just written `^.{6,15}$` which would match any string between 6 and 15 characters in length (inclusive).
- `.test(password)` The previous mess created a `RegExp` object. Now we're calling the `test()` method, passing in our password. This will return `true` if the regex matches (i.e. the password meets our requirements) or `false` if the password fails.
- `)` Close paren. Simple but important.